# JDBC transaction for resultSet

Tags: jdbc

Do I need to start and commit transaction while iterate result set?

like the following:

```
String query = ....;
Connection con = ... // create the connection
con.setAutoCommit(false);
try (Statement stmt = con.createStatement()) {
  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
  while (rs.next()) {
     //do things here
  }
} catch (SQLException e) {
  // roll back
}
```

I see that it does work without active transaction and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If auto-commit is enabled, then the driver will start(*) a transaction for you when you execute a statement, and it will end as soon as execution completes (for a query, that is when you processed all rows or closed the result set, or execution resulted in an exception), or when you execute another statement.

When you disable auto-commit mode, the driver will start a transaction when it is needed (for example, when you execute a statement), but the transaction will need to be manually ended by calling `Connection.commit()` or `Connection.rollback()` (or when you enable auto-commit mode again). When you don't explicitly end a transaction, it will remain active until you close the connection (at which point most drivers will rollback, but some - for example Oracle - will commit).

In short, JDBC does not offer a way to explicitly start a transaction, it will start one when necessary. In your example, the transaction was started at `stmt.executeQuery(query)`.

---

<sup>*: This is actually an implementation detail, for some databases, auto-commit mode might be handled entirely server-side</sup>

Comment: So if I omit the  con.setAutoCommit(false); line in my example when the transaction will end? only after the iterator finish consume all rows from result set?

Comment: @user1409534 Details vary a bit per driver, but normally in auto-commit mode you can expect that the transaction commits when the last row has been fetched.

Comment: I see thank you. And if I use hibernate scroll method on Query object without transaction can I expect the same?